# Finding all Google Accounts from a Domain

Tags: google, domains, email

I dealing with issues regarding employees using email addresses from the company domain to sign up for google services. I dealing with both reckless employees forgetting the credentials and malicious former employees using linked accounts.

I have access to all email accounts using the company's domain. Is there a way to find out all google services that have been signed up using a email address from my domain?

Answer (score 2):

***Google accounts are not owned by those who operate the email service***

Google will not reveal that information because you do not 'own' any rights to those personal accounts. An email address is simply a means of signing up, it has little bearing in ownership of an account as users can change email address at anytime.

***Prevention***

It is the employers responsibility to police the email service that you provide and not Googles. If you wish to prevent users future users using Google searches or any other then you can:

- Block the verification email that Google sends out to verify email accounts.
- Block the internal network reaching `https://www.google.com/a/signup`
- Signup to Google G Suite and add the domain, then block all services.

***Find Google Accounts***

Since Google will not reveal that information then you can search internally within the inboxes of all your users for the welcome email that Google sends out, then you know which accounts that have Google accounts.

Comment: Searching email accounts wont help.

Comment: Why wont it? it'll identify who's signed up to the service... Just because you don't like what you hear doesn't make it untrue. Google has strict privacy terms... you do not own the rights to those accounts therefore Google will not even enter discussion about them.

Comment: The needed emails have been deleted and the user had access to create and delete accounts.

Answer (score 2):

If your employer is managing email using Google Gsuite (https://gsuite.google.com/), you will need admin access of Google Gsuite. The admin access will provide you with ability to delete users. Once you delete an user from the account, all its associated Google services account will also be deleted.

In the case where your employer is not using Google Gsuite, it is manual task for each email address. You need to sign in to Google using each individual employee email and delete the account from all Google services at https://myaccount.google.com/intro/preferences#deleteservices.